# Event handler bind to an anonymous function vs named function

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

**I know `.on()` exists with jQuery** and `.bind()` should not be used in the future, considering that I have a version of jQuery greater than or equal to 1.7.

What I want to know is this: are there are any differences between attaching an anonymous function or named function to an event handler using `.bind()`?

***Example:***

```
// Anonymous function
$(".warning").bind("click", function(){
   alert("Hello");
});

// Named function
$(".warning").bind("click", foo);

function foo(){
   alert("Hello");
}
```

Imagine that I have 100 `div`'s with the class `warning` in my page. The function `.bind()` will attach a new function to every handler with an anonymous function but will it be exactly the same with a named function in the very internal of JavaScript and jQuery?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There won't be any noticeable performance difference.

One main difference is that with a named function you can also selectively unbind functions and not just all functions associated with an event type.

Of course, this can also help you avoid code duplication.

Comment: What if there are dynamic DOM elements added a bunch of times, and the event handler should be attached each time they are added - could there be a performance different then (I'm actually asking, this is not a cynical remark).